# What's the difference between DAO and DP patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, dataprovider, data-access-object

What is the difference between Data Access Objects (DAO) and Data provider (DP) patterns?

I've read about them and it seems to me that they're the same except that .NET uses the data provider terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually both specify an entity which exposes a set of customized methods to read from or write to a database.

Indeed the term '**DAO**' is the more generic one to use. **DP** is a term introduced by Microsoft in their products to do the exactly same work. You can refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08(v=vs.110).aspx) for more detail about DPs.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use DataProvider when I just want to 'provide' a database in form of an instance. In this case, I don't have permission to write this instance back in database. I've just pick up these data to read.

But when I use DAO I'm allowing to permission to use all CRUD operations, as normal.